# Onion sets and rain

Tags: onions, rain

I'm in the UK. planted snowball onion sets a few days go (soil was potting mix. They're in tubs with holes in the bottom.) There are days of heavy rain ahead, will they be all right?

Comment: What part of the world are you in and what type of soil is it.

Comment: What is the worry about? Rain?